# Firefox: Click event not calling on SPAN tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am having a weird issue on my personal site. I am revamping it and have a few DIVs and SPAN elements. For some unknown reason Firefox is not calling the click event I attached via jQuery. Code works fine on Chrome. Below is the example URL:

http://adnansiddiqi.com/main.html

WHen you click on any of the box, say ABOUT box, it then shows the page and a cross **X** on right, **upon hovering it should show a HAND cursor and on click it should reset the state**, that is bringing box well. THe code works perfect on Chrome(Mac) but not on FireFox 11(Mac)

Pardon me if it's violation of terms of sharing personal URL but God knows I tried my best to paste the main code on jsFiddle but sadly the require jsFiddle code is not executing properly on CHrome either so I had no choice left other than giving the actual URL. Though I removed all things that gives any personal touch. Fiddle's link is given below:

http://jsfiddle.net/RGL7a/20/

I am pulling my hair and find no sensible clue of it.

Kindly help me!

Thanks

Comment: I think your div#bigcontent is obscuring your cross, the -10% margin maybe, also ff does not support the hand value for cursor use pointer instead.

Comment: but it's working on CHrome, you may test it out yourself. I mean the cross click

Comment: Yes, you are right. It's the Bigcontent overlapping the X div. Thanks Bro, make it as an Answer and I will accept it

Comment: It's working fine for me in FF on Win7. Could it be something simple like clearing your cache? Sounds dumb but has worked for me.

Comment: I am having issues on FF11 for Mac. No it was not a cache issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

div#bigcontent is obscuring your cross, the -10% margin maybe, also ff does not support the hand value for cursor use pointer instead.

Answer (score 2):

First off the `hand` value to the `cursor` property is an old Microsoft declaration. You can see its support in the different browsers on this page:
http://www.quirksmode.org/css/cursor.html

The "new" way of showing this cursor hand, is using the `pointer` value. So changing this `hand` value to `pointer`, would help a bit. But not all the way.

The other problem, which is the main problem, is that you cannot click the cross. The reason is, that there is a division on a layer on top of it. For solving this problem, I would `absolute` `position` this element and give it a very high `z-index`, so that you are sure that the cross is always on top. 
So i would change the styling for the `.cross` to the following:

```
.cross {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    font-weight: bolder;
    font-size: 2.0em;
    float: right;
    color: #B9C0C7;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 25px; //this puts the element right underneath the top bar
    right: 2%; //so that it has the same distance from the right side, as you defined with padding-right
}
```

I hope this was of any help :)